# How to iterate over xml node with version and value as elements and pick the value with the max version in python?

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I have a xml with elements "version" and "Name", "ID" in it. I need to browse through it and for every "name" find the max version and return the name and ID for it.

E.g. XML-

```
-<env:Body>
 -<group>
   <"version">1</"version">
   <"name">Test1</"name">
   <"ID">999</"ID">
 </group>
 -<group>
   <"version">2</"version">
   <"name">Test1</"name">
   <"ID">998</"ID">
 </group>
 -<group>
   <"version">10</"version">
   <"name">Test2</"name">
   <"ID">123</"ID">
 </group>
 -<group>
   <"version">11</"version">
   <"name">Test2</"name">
   <"ID">223</"ID">
 </group>
 -<group>
   <"version">0</"version">
   <"name">Test1</"name">
   <"ID">1008</"ID">
 </group>
</env:Body>
```

This can have thousands of groups.
I want the resultant xml with only the latest groups(highest version numbers), like this -

```
-<env:Body>
 -<group>
   <"version">2</"version">
   <"name">Test1</"name">
   <"ID">998</"ID">
 </group>
 -<group>
   <"version">11</"version">
   <"name">Test2</"name">
   <"ID">223</"ID">
 </group>
</env:Body>
```

Doing this in python2.7. Cannot paste the actual xml due to restrictions. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: If it were me I'd use XSLT to do this transform. You can run XSLT 1.0 with [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt). Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is done using the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: Thanks, let me try that

Comment: If you run into issues, update your question with what you’re trying and we’d be happy to help you figure it out.